# Menu items not appearing programmatically ionic 3 when user signs in. (AWS Cognito)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, amazon-cognito

I am building an ionic app using AWS as a backend (has been challenging!), and for some reason on my user sign-in page, I got this nasty bug that wasn't there when I was using firebase as the backend. In a nutshell, my side menu has items that should appear based on whether the user is logged in or not. If the user is logged in, the menu should have a logout item. If the user is not logged in, the menu should either not have any options, or a redundant sign-in option.

I got the hard part down, which was setting up AWS Cognito to work the sign-in logic, and setting the correct root page, however, after a user logs in, the menu does not show the logout option.

Funny thing, if I reload the app, the menu does show the logout option. Not sure why. Also weird, after I reload the app and I click the logout button, the correct options for a user that is not logged in do appear in the menu. If someone can take a look and tell me why the menu options only render correctly when I log out and if I log in only after I reload the app, I would be very grateful! Thank you in advance for your time! Code below...

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { SignInPage } from '../pages/sign-in/sign-in';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any;
  isLoggedIn //this variable holds the status of the user and determines the menu items;

  constructor(platform: Platform, 
              statusBar: StatusBar, 
              splashScreen: SplashScreen, 
              private menuCtrl: MenuController,
              private authService: AuthService) {

    this.verifyUserstate(); //method to check if a user is logged in
    console.log(this.isLoggedIn); //debug line
    console.log(this.menuCtrl.get()); //debug line

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

onLoad(page: any) {
 console.log("onLoad");
 this.nav.setRoot(page);
 this.menuCtrl.close();
}

onLogout() {
 this.authService.logout();
 this.verifyUserstate();
 this.menuCtrl.close();
}

verifyUserstate() {
  console.log("in verify userstate");
  this.authService.isAuthenticated()
  .then(() => {
    this.isLoggedIn = true; //if a user is logged in = true
    this.rootPage = TabsPage;
    console.log(this.isLoggedIn); // more debug
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.isLoggedIn = false; //if user is not logged in = false
    this.rootPage = SignInPage;
    console.log(this.isLoggedIn); //more debug
  });
 }
}
```

app.html:

```
<ion-menu [content]="nav">
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <button ion-item icon-left (click)="onLoad(signinPage)" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn"> <!-- check isLoggin-->
            <ion-icon name="log-in"></ion-icon>
            Sign In
        </button>
        <button ion-item icon-left (click)="onLogout()" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
            <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
            Log Out
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

auth.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AlertController } from "ionic-angular";
import { CognitoUserPool, AuthenticationDetails, CognitoUser, CognitoUserSession } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";


const POOL_DATA = {
    UserPoolId: "xx-xxxx-X_XXXX",
    ClientId: "You do not need to know :)"
}

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(POOL_DATA);

export class AuthService {

signin(email: string, password: string) {
    let message: string;
    var authenticationData = {
        Username : email,
        Password : password,
    };

    var authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
    let userData = {
        Username: email,
        Pool: userPool
    }

    let cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
            onSuccess(result: CognitoUserSession) {
                console.log(result)
                resolve("Success!")
            },
            onFailure(error) {
                let message: string = error.message;
                reject(message);
            }
}

logout() {
    this.getAuthenticatedUser().signOut();
}

isAuthenticated() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let user = this.getAuthenticatedUser();

        if (user) {
                user.getSession((err, session) => {
                    if(session.isValid()) {
                        resolve(true);
                    } else if (err) {
                        reject(err.message);
                    }
                })
        } else {
            reject("Not authenticated");
        }
    });
}
```

}

Finally, the sign-in.ts file (where the magic of login in happens):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoadingController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller';
import { MyApp } from '../../app/app.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-sign-in',
  templateUrl: 'sign-in.html',
})
export class SignInPage {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
              private alertCtrl: AlertController,
              private navCtrl: NavController) {
  } 

  onSignin(form: NgForm) {
    const loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Signing you in..."
    });
loading.present();

this.authService.signin(form.value.email, form.value.password)
.then(data => {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyApp); /*navigate to myApp again to reverify the 
                                *login status. This sets the right rootPage, 
                                *but I have a feeling here also lies the menu problem.
                                */
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: "Oops",
        message: error,
        buttons: ["Ok"]
      });

      alert.present();
    })
    loading.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your verifyUserstate function isn't called on Login.

Comment: @felix9607 it is. I get all the console.log outputs expected. I have a feeling that the menu items get rendered before my verifyUser method finishes, though.